# Pseudo-polynomial algorithm for the subset sum problem - also negative numbers in the set

Tags: algorithms

Is it possible to build a pseudo-polynomial algorithm subset sum problem for a set of numbers in which there are also negative values?

I found a certain code in Python and it seems to work.

Is it possible?

Edit:

I add a source: https://gist.github.com/klittlepage/26bad9c7e4ee727fc366093850ca36a3

Comment: I think you should post the source code here to add some context to your problem.

Comment: Ok. I added   :-)

Comment: It seems [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) has what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I see. It is possible.